# Debug profile does not exists error after VS 2019 update when running azure function

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

Can't debug azure function from Visual Studio 2019 after updating to version 16.10.0. Getting following error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with this issue was it is not properly installed that referenced version of Azure Function Tools. So when it was downloaded partially it is not even trying to re-install it. So I was able to re-install it by doing the following workaround.

1. Removed the existing installation folder (C:\Users\SithiraP\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.23.4)
2. Created a new Azure Function app from visual studio. (It is downloading again  Azure Function Tools when creating a new Azure function project)

Comment: Thank you very much. That answer worked for me. I deleted the folder and reran my Function. That's all!

Comment: @HenryGuillen17 could you please set this as Accepted answer

Comment: This is not my question, I'm sorry. I could only vote positively

Answer (score 5):

I faced the issue recently and tried to download again the tools but it wasn't working even after the download. So I found out that the installation path was

```
...\Releases\3.23.5\cli\...
```

and I copied the same `cli` folder and renamed it to `cli_x64`

```
...\Releases\3.23.5\cli_x64\...
```

and it worked fine

Comment: Where do you find the installation path?

Comment: You may check in you ...AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.23.5 @hiFI

Comment: Is there anywhere I could download the 64bit files that are required for it?

Answer (score 1):

I copied all folders from 3.28.1 into 3.23.5 and it worked for me since 3.28.1 had cli_x64

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

i found cli_64 folder is missing there so I copied this folder from 3.28.1 folder and pasted into 3.20 folder it worked for me