# Azure function don't start locally

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have Azure Function and try to start in locally, but after starting command line is show and hide during less than 1 sec. I tried to catch it on screenshot:

[image]

it looks like no correct parameters for start.

my local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
  }
}
```

my csproj file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.22.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Libraries\Tms.Services\Tms.Services.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Libraries\Tms.SlackNotificationCore\Tms.SlackNotificationCore.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Libraries\Verizon\VerizonApiImplementation\VerizonApiImplementation.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Files\EmailTemplate\DailyExtremelyHighUsageNotificationTemplate.html">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Files\EmailTemplate\DailyExtremelyHighUsageNotificationTemplate.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

also, I set "Executable" Launch on Debug property window and full path:

[image]

because without it azure function could not start at all locally with error:

> ### --------------------------- Microsoft Visual Studio
> --------------------------- The debug executable 'C:\Users\OLEG\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.23.5\cli_x64\func.exe'
> specified in the '...' debug profile does not exist.
> --------------------------- OK

Where can I check it?

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the problem is. What does the csproj file look like? Do you have any custom startup code?

Comment: @DavidG added something to main post

Comment: The `Launch` property should be set to `Project`. But you still haven't shown the contents of the csproj file.

Comment: @DavidG then I get "The debug executable '...' specified in the '...' debug profile does not exist."

Comment: The executable path should be empty and the output type should be set to class library with no startup object.

Comment: @DavidG I have the same :( Don't know what is necessary to check more....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cause of `Azure function version tools` and `references` may not downloaded properly.

Two ways to fix this problem

***Remove*** the existing `installation folder` (C:\Users\OLEG\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.23.5\cli_x64\func.exe)

And ***create*** a new `Azure Function` app from visual studio. It will download the new azure function tools and references.

Or

You can **rename** your installation path `….\Releases\3.23.5\cli_x64\…`  into `….\Releases\3.23.5\cli\...`

Refer [here for similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67798635/debug-profile-does-not-exists-error-after-vs-2019-update-when-running-azure-func)

Comment: thank you very much, you save my day (or probably several days)